RegisterManySingleton as named instances
I want to inject all registered implementaions of a base interface as a collection, but I also want to resolve them as more concrete interface implementations.
For the collection resolving to work, I need to register them as named instances
To be able to resolve them by base or derived interface, I need to use RegisterManySingleton
Is there a way to combine these 2 requirements?
something like
containerRegistry.RegisterManySingleton<ServiceOne>(typeof(IInitialize), typeof(IServiceOne), "one");
containerRegistry.RegisterManySingleton<ServiceTwo>(typeof(IInitialize), typeof(IServiceTwo), "two");

usage:
public interface IInitialize
{
  void Initialize();
}

public interface IServiceOne : IInitialize
{
}

public interface IServiceTwo : IInitialize
{
}

public class Initializer
{
  public Initializer(IInitialize[] services)
  {
  }
}

public class Foo
{
  public Foo(IServiceOne service)
  {
  }
}


You can use the GetContainer extension method to retrieve the underlying UnityContainer and circumvent the ContainerRegistry if you need more than it wants to offer.

For some reason I could not find GetContainer on IContainerRegistry, I have Prism v8

First of all Unity Container is a terrible choice since it's end of life and missing a number of features which is why it's been dropped from active support for all but WPF which is only to help maintain legacy apps.
Second while DryIoc actually uses an internal API that doesn't work this way, the other Prism containers do actually replicate the behavior by registering the concrete type as a Singleton and then resolving that concrete singleton for the interfaces, so it's already doing what you're asking.

That's exactly what I have, existing WPF app
